# With Flask-Admin and Flask how can I submit a form\view based on ModelView from code?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-admin

With Flask-Admin and Flask how can I submit a form\view based on ModelView from code?

I'm trying to create a separate view\form that would allow user to add multiple entries with one form. Specifically allowing to upload multiple images with common prefix name and common parameters. I'd like to do it by submitting a single-image upload form from code, because it does some additional processing like resizing images and I'd like to let Flask-Admin handle connecting database entries and files.

Here's the form I'd like to submit from code:

```py
class ImageView(ModelView):
    def _list_thumbnail(view, context, model, name):
        if not model.path:
            return ''

        return Markup('<img src="%s">' % url_for('media',
                                                 filename=form.thumbgen_filename(model.path)))

    column_labels = dict(show_in_header="Show In Header?",
                         path="Image")

    form_create_rules = ("name",
                         "tags",
                         rules.Text(
                             "Use this image as header. If more than one image is selected header image will be random each time the page is loaded."),
                         "show_in_header",
                         "path")
    form_excluded_columns = ("timestamp")

    column_formatters = {
        'path': _list_thumbnail
    }

    thumbnail_size = config("media", "thumbnail_size")

    form_extra_fields = {
        'path': BroImageUploadField('Image',
                                    base_path=IMAGES_FOLDER,
                                    thumbnail_size=(thumbnail_size, thumbnail_size, True),
                                    endpoint="media",
                                    url_relative_path='media',
                                    relative_path=None)
    }

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        # redirect to login page if user doesn't have access
        return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
```

And here I'm creating a form and I'm just not sure that `.process()` is the function to submit it? Is there one at all?

```py
lass MultipleImagesUploadView(BaseView):
    @expose("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def index(self):
        if request.method == "POST":
            a_form = MultipleImagesForm(request.form)
            base_name = a_form.base_name.data
            tags = a_form.tags.data
            show_in_header = a_form.show_in_header.data
            print (request.files.getlist(a_form.images.name))
            uploaded_files = request.files.getlist(a_form.images.name)
            for i, uf in enumerate(uploaded_files):
                try:
                    name, ext = os.path.splitext(uf.filename)
                    if ext not in IMAGE_EXTENSIONS:
                        flash("Image file {} was skipped as it's extension is not supported ({}).".format(uf.filename, ext), category="warning")
                        continue
                    image_contents = uf.stream.read()
                    image_form = ImageView()
                    image_form.name.data = "{}_{}".format(base_name, i)
                    image_form.tags.data = tags
                    image_form.show_in_header.data = show_in_header
                    image_form.path.data = image_contents
                    image_form.process()
                except Exception as e:
                    flash ("Unhandled exception: {}".format(e), category="warning")
            flash("Images were added to the gallery.", category='success')

        a_form = MultipleImagesForm()
        print("############", a_form)
        return self.render('/admin/multiple_images_upload.html', form=a_form)
```

I can't figure out a way to submit a form from code, been trying to find the answer in docs and google for hours now with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. In my case I was missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Without that files part was sent as empty.

Also changed to using `from flask_wtf import FlaskForm` and enabling it as `{{ form.files(class="form-control", multiple="") }}` in the template.

Files can then be accessed with `uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("files")` on POST request, it will hold array of file-objects.

I hope this helps someone. If any additional formatting is required I will add or expand the answer.